# Problems while installing Postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I was trying to install Postgres several times, but it didn't work out. 
I am using Mac and I tried to install Postgress.app, I got problems with database connection. 
I decided to install Postgress using HomeBrew.

At the beginning, I uninstalled all the versions: 
Using `brew remove --force postgresql` to remove all versions

I used 
brew cleanup posgtres as well

Then, launched the installation using home brew

```
> ==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/postgresql-
> Already downloaded:
> /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.3.2.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
> ==> Pouring postgresql-9.3.2.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
> ==> Caveats If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed, you may need to remove the previous version first. See:   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/issue/2510
> 
> To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.3) of
> PostgreSQL, see:  
> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html
> 
> When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended: 
> ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
> 
> To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.
> 
> To reload postgresql after an upgrade:
>     launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
>     launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Any recommendation to install Postgres right way on my machine.

Comment: Even though I never tried to install pgsql/pg in Mac, it looks like you have installed/downloaded the 8.x version and the complain is about that. It seems your OS hasn't been cleaned enough so far.

Comment: What does this have to do with GIS.SE? Is the server running? Did you follow the instructions to reload postgresql? What are the errors? What debugging have you done? What were the results of that? Please edit the question to include this important information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's a PATH issue. Mac OSX Lion includes PostgreSQL in the system now ([version 8.4](http://jonathandean.com/2011/08/postgresql-8-4-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/)) in `/usr/bin/pgsql`
2. then you install [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/) (version 9.x)
3. and you have here a problem with the installed versions, look at [Upgrading From A Previous Version](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_0).
4. then you use `brew remove --force postgresql` or `brew cleanup posgtres`. But these commands removes any previous version of PostgreSQL **installed by Homebrew** (in `usr/local/bin/psql`) and not those installed previously.
5. thus, you must first [uninstall Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_22)  and must adapt your PATH to use the Homebrew version: [Brew Install Postgresql on OS X Lion](http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/)

Another solution is to use the [PostgreSQL/PostGIS solution](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) of KyngChaos (as a Framework).